# Why does header file have a separate implementation file? (Is my professor correct?)

Tags: c++, oop

Before, this question is marked as duplicate, My intention is to not duplicate it, but to rather find out whether the answer that my professor gave me regarding this question (when asked in class) is correct or not. The reason why I am skeptical is because I do not see any way of how his answer would be practical or even possible in a real-world scenario.

The answer that my professor gave was related to the security of the implementation file. He said that if we were to not separate the implementation file from the header file, than anyone using this header file will also get access to the implementation of the functions. However, if we had a separate implementation file, then it would add security (HOW?) to the implementation for the class functions because people will only be able to see the declarations and not its definition (WHY NOT?).

Another reason that he gave was because of the compilation. He said that the header file will be compiled every time the program will run, where a cpp file will create an object file and will not be compiled every time. (THIS MADE SENSE).

**Can someone please verify the integrity of this answer because I cannot find it**

With much thanks!

Comment: if you provide headers and compiled version to somebody, then they can't

Comment: @RiaD i did not understand?

Comment: It can be accurate in the sense of distributing a proprietary library as only headers and compiled object code. That's not really "security" though but just a way to hide the source code.

Comment: Well, I do not remember the exact words but I remember him saying ```security``` somewhere in the answer.

Comment: Without knowing the exact things your prof said and the exact questions you asked, this seems too broad or opinion-based. If you want more info on his statement, just ask him?

Comment: In college they did this all the time. They would compile the CPP file, and then send us the OBJ file and the H file and say "black-box test this". Since the CPP file was compiled to an OBJ file, we didn't have the source. It's called "Security by Obscurity"

Comment: @RiaD aren't all header files compiled?

Comment: @RiaD Compiled files can be disassembled / reverse engineered. There's no "security" in compiled files versus source files. Just a layer of obfuscation that a skilled attacker can easily defeat. Don't believe that just because you compiled your code it is now secure and uninspectable.

Comment: @Andy Yeaaaah I remember him saying that exact word now!

Comment: @ProgrammingRage A header that only declares things provides nothing to compile... What gets compiled are _translation units_, i.e. source files plus all their includes. But headers are also used when distributing libraries, to let users know what they can use in that library, while they only get it in compiled form and not as C++ source files. For instance, a proprietary library, or simply an open-source library provided in compiled form.

Comment: So its not at all secure basically.

Comment: The binary-and-headers-only library case is ostensibly a bit more "secure" than publishing your full code, algorithms, etc for all your competitors to see and life-and-shift... but then ultimately it's still code, albeit machine code, and that can be reverse-engineered given enough time/effort. So, not much more secure, but maybe enough to dissuade some.

Comment: @underscore_d So the only advantage is that the implementation file makes sure that the headers declarations are compiled only once.

Comment: Again, _declarations_ are not compiled. Having the _definitions_ in _translation units_ be compiled separately means they don't have to be recompiled every time if nothing they include has been modified.

Comment: @underscore_d How do I make sure that others receive my compiled form and not my code? How do I do that?

Comment: Well, first you have to compile it... and how to do _that_ is too basic/broad a question for SO, I would say.

Comment: @underscore_d Actually that is what I mean. Since I am a beginner in C++, I am easily mixing up the terms. I sincerely apologize.

Comment: You should search the internet for "PIMPL idiom".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank You!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews This is way too advanced for me to understand. I have not yet studied interfaces or binary compatibility yet. I read this site: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pimpl-idiom-in-c-with-examples/

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am not saying that's a good way to create security. It's just what might have been meant. Also it was somewhat an answer to previous (now deleted)comment

Comment: Basically, you have a class or interface defined that is public; something other Users can see.  The interface has a pointer to the implementation.  The implementation is private and not available to Users.  Consider that the public class would be in your library header file and the implementation would be part of your build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If we're talking about C than it seems reasonable:

```
// foo.h
struct MyObject;

struct MyObject *CreateAnObject();
void DoSomethingWithAnObject(struct MyObject *);

// foo.c
struct MyObject {
   int a;
   int b;
};

struct MyObject *CreateAnObject() {
  struct MyObject *obj = malloc(sizeof(*obj));
  ...
  return obj;
}

void DoSomethingWithAnObject(struct MyObject *) {
  ...
}
```

Here, the users of your header file can't muck around with the contents of
'MyObject' because they don't have knowledge of the contents of it.

## However, in C++...

We explicitly have the ability to mark parts of a class as public or private. So there's no real object security need to hide the contents of the object.

```
// foo.hpp
class MyObject {
 public:
   MyObject();
   void DoSomething();

 private:
   int a;
   int b;
};

// foo.cpp
MyObject::MyObject() { ... }
void MyObject::DoSomething() { ... }
```

Comment: Since I do not know 'C', why the users cannot muck around the contents?

Comment: I can still see that `MyObject` has two data members.  Maybe the OP needs to review the PIMPL idiom.

Comment: @ProgrammingRage It's common in C to only forward-declare `struct`s in headers & make users do everything with them via functions that take pointers. Those are called _opaque types_ because the internals are not shown/ not depended-on at compile time. So the implementor can change the internals later without requiring end-users to recompile. However, that's more about avoiding recompilation or unwanted use of internals than "security". In C++, access modifiers let us prevent others using internal details, but they can still _see_ them. The 'pimpl' idiom then is a way to do opaque types in C++